# Grails equivalents to Rails console Book.all, Book.create, etc

Tags: grails

I am relatively new to Grails, and want to learn more about how to create some quick mock data while developing my app.

In Ruby on Rails, i can use the console to create new objects, like so:

```
Book.create{title: "new book", author_id: 2}
```

And with Rails i can see all like so:

```
Book.all
```

What are the grails equivalents for this? I am using Grails 2.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an in-memory database during development the easiest way to
add testdata is to add code to *Bootstrap.groovy* that creates and saves
data.

Another option is to use the Grails Console: http://www.grails.org/Command+Line+Tools

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Grails shell (as Michael alludes to). For example, here I have a test app with a domain class `test.Book`.  In this example, I first load the Grails interactive mode, run the app, then run the shell and test saving and listing a `Book` entry:

```
/home/tim/cmdline $ grails
| Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion: 
grails> run-app
| Compiling 38 source files

| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/cmdline
| Application loaded in interactive mode. Type 'exit' to shutdown.
| Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion: 
grails> shell
| Packaging Grails application.....
Groovy Shell (1.8.4, JVM: 1.6.0_29)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> new test.Book( title:'Groovy things' ).save()
===> test.Book : 1
groovy:000> test.Book.list()
===> [test.Book : 1]
groovy:000>
```

Comment: is it possible to run the grails console while the app is running? Don't the two of them try to use the same port. I usually use the Grails console plugin to avoid this problem

Comment: The shell by itself won't start the web listener and run-app is not required for the shell to work. So they won't conflict and you can use both at the same time

Answer (score 4):

If you install the [Grails console plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console), and navigate to `/console`, you can create objects using

```
new Book(title: "new book").save()
```

and get a list of all books using

```
Book.list()
```